# Configure website to use memcache

Tags: php, memcached

I have installed (or better my host has installed) memcached at my VPS.
I want to configure it for my website, as i am not so expert on this things, I am trying to ask some help here at stackoverflow.
Please can some send me a guide, or make here a guide how to configure memcached to run for my website ?

Thank you
Best Regards
Meo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only running one server, it would make a lot more sense to use [APC](http://php.net/apc)
instead of Memcached. Memcached really shines when you have multiple web nodes and need to share a cache across them. APC will cache things in memory locally, avoiding a trip across the network, and is also an opcode cache, resulting in an awesome speed boost!

Anyways, to answer your question, you can use the [memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) extension. Documentation is available [in the PHP manual](http://us.php.net/memcached).

Comment: hello, yes i have only one website, so you suggest to uninstall memcached and use APC instead ? APC will need further configurations to work ? or just it will start automatically to cache? if need configurations, please can i have any kind of guide here or at another link ? thank you

Comment: @Meo: right--in that case I'd recommend APC. Once you install it and enable it in php.ini, it will start working as opcode cache. To use it as a data cache, you'll need to use functions such as apc_store/apc_fetch -- see PHP manual for more info (PHP manual is excellent, everything you need there :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook PHP into memcache.

http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/using-memcache-with-mysql-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

Here a very simple class to implement memcached on your website very easy:

http://simple_memcache.onlinephpfunctions.com/